# how can i call a function when a template loads in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am new to angular2. I have a requirement to call a function when a template loads/initializes. I know how to do this in angular1.x., but I am not able to find out how it can be done in angular-2.

### This is how I tried in angular1.x

### In html

```
<div ng-init="getItems()">
//some logic to get my items
</div>
```

### In controller

```
getItems = function(){
console.log('in the getitems function call');
//logic to get my items from db/localStorage
}
```

This is how I used ng-init in angular1.x, but there is no ng-init in angular-2?Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Component({
 ...
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    // when component class instance is created
  }

  ngOnChanges(...) {
    // when inputs are updated
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // after `ngOnChanges()` was called the first time
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // after the view was created
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // after content was projected
  }
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-overview for the full list

Comment: if i declare ngAfterViewInit() function in my component , what ever the logic in that function will reflected to my view when it gets loaded.please clarify me? thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What do you mean by " will reflected to my view". If you have  `<div>{{someProp}}</div>` in the view, it will be updated whenever change detection runs. Angular2 doesn't like the model to be changed during change detection. You'll get the https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005 (expression has changed ...) error. `ngOnInit()`, `ngOnChanges()` are such methods that are called by change detection (don't remember about the others). I would need more details about what you try to accomplish exactly to give more concrete feedback.

Comment: sorry my question itself worng.. what i mean is that  
if i declare ngAfterViewInit() function in my component, i am having logic as getting the names from localstorage. if my template loads the ngAfterViewInit() fun called(as i done in angular-1.x using ng-init) so that i can get the values from LocalStorage, therefore i can displayed in html.there is no sign of changing. just to display.

Comment: "there is no sign of changing. just to display. " In Angular2 you usually assign values to properties (changing) and bindings in view update when change detection detects properties have been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check lifecycle events of a component https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html . From what you are saying you probably needs ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 1):

In angular2 you can use component phase `ngOnInit` it is equal to on-init in angularJS. Here is more information about [lifecycle in angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

Example:

```
export class PeekABoo implements OnInit {
 constructor(private logger: LoggerService) { }

 // implement OnInit's `ngOnInit` method
 ngOnInit() { 
  this.logIt(`OnInit`); 
 }

 protected logIt(msg: string) {
  this.logger.log(`#${nextId++} ${msg}`);
 }
}
```